# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using `devise` and trying to force the user to sign in.
after he signed in, I want to check if his email is found in the table of workers. if it exists, redirect him to: `/workers`, else to `/tasksadmins`.

I tried:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :is_worker

  def is_worker

     @email = current_user.email
     tag = Worker.where(:email => @email)
     if tag.nil?
        redirect_to '/tasksadmins'
     else
        redirect_to '/workers'
     end
  end
end
```

but I got:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :is_worker

  def is_worker
    if user_signed_in?
       @email = current_user.try(:email)
      if @email && Worker.find_by_email(@email).nil?
        redirect_to '/tasksadmins'
      else
        redirect_to '/workers'
      end
    else
        redirect_to '/users/sign_in' # devise?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, sorry... I've just noticed you have updated your question

```
#SessionsController

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || session[:user_return_to] || root_path
end


#Your controller

before_filter :user_return_to
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :is_worker

def is_worker
   @email = current_user.try(:email)
   if @email && Worker.find_by_email(@email).nil?
      redirect_to '/tasksadmins'
   else
      redirect_to '/workers'
   end
end

private

def user_return_to
  session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
end
```

Dynamic finders like **.find_by_email** returns single object (first matched) or **nil** otherwise.

But **.where()** always returns AR::Relation which can be blank* (empty*) and **never nil**.

**AR::Relation responds to .blank? and .empty? delegating these methods to collection which actually Array.* So the code:

```
tag = Worker.where(:email => @email)
if tag.nil?
```

will always return **false**

Comment: thank you.. but when I tried to enter: "localhost:3000/workers", I have to be redirected to 'users/sign_in' but I got: Oops! It was not possible to show this website

Comment: if you use devise and your account model is User. then try updated code.

Comment: I add an update to my topic. please take a look. I got error: 
Oops! It was not possible to show this website

The website at http://localhost:3000/workers seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Too many redirects

Comment: Try another. Each action call remembers current path and stores it in session. But i don't know yet devise's behavior when user tries to login many times after redirection.

Comment: I have to define a controller that is called: "session", right?

Comment: I have in the controllers only the: "ApplicationController", "WorkersController" and "TasksadminsController" :/ I don't have the folder: users :/

Comment: so configure it by hand https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Answer (score 1):

If the user does not authenticate successfully, cuurent_user would be nil. Am I correct in assuming that you are using devise for authentication?

Comment: thank you!
yes, I'm using devise.. so how can I fix it please?

Comment: as `before_filter :authenticate_user!` is there, why `is_worker` going to execute ? logically request should redirect to /login page with error messages. Am i correct ?

Comment: @rkp, yes, if the user is not sign in, redirect to users/sign_in.
if he signed in and is found in the table of workers, redirect to: "/workers", else redirect to "/tasksadmins"

Answer (score 1):

```
 def is_worker
     render :template => '/login' and return if current_user.nil?
     @email = current_user.email
     tag = Worker.where(:email => @email)
     if tag.nil?
        redirect_to '/tasksadmins'
     else
        redirect_to '/workers'
     end
  end
```

Comment: thank you but I got: Template is missing

Missing template users/sign_in with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/alon/projects/TODOLIST/app/views" * "/home/alon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.2.0.rc/app/views"